# How to protect a folder in Apache but allow PHP scripts to access it?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, directory

I've been thinking a lot about this and can't find a way to do it, maybe it's not possible or maybe I just can't think of way. That's why I'm posting this here right...

Basically, I need to protected a folder in Apache from prying eyes, but on the other hand, I need some PHP scripts to access the contents of that folder.

Is this achievable?

P.S: I don't know if this question belongs here or in StackOverflow... My guess is that it belongs in both, but I had to choose one site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean your PHP script must access this folder locally, but you want to protect it from serving to clients, it is very easy:

```
<Directory /whatever/you/want/protect>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

If not, please specify the exact situation, what you want to solve.

Comment: This question was asked more than 1 year ago, I don't even remember it's context :/ But I believe it was something like giving a 403 when people tried to access `http://www.mysite.com/some/folder/` but if they opened `http://www.mysite.com/some_script.php` that needed to access `/some/folder` to read some data, it needed to work.

Comment: The deny directive solves this problem anyway. Sorry for necroposting :-)

Comment: So, just so I know, will your solution work to the problem I just described or not? Did you test it? I'm a little confused...

Comment: I know it works, i copied it from a working webserver.

Answer (score 1):

If the PHP script runs as a user that is not a shared one (something other than www, for instance) then you can just use standard Unix file permissions.

It is a good idea to use different users for every application to keep a compromise in one from killing another.  If you run each application in this way, only the user running the script needs to access any of the private bits.

Comment: Isn't there any other way?